# How to get list stored in Python dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, automation

I have a dictionary where every key has multiple values assigned as a list.

Output looks like this:

```
>>> print(db_state)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'787777': ['firstdb', 'online', 'seconddb', 'enabled', 'thirtdb', 'terminated'], '332123': ['forthdb', 'terminated', 'fifthdb', 'online'], '85756': ['sixthdb', 'online'], '85787673': ['seventhdb', 'enabled', 'eighthdb', 'terminated'] ...
```

Code that gives mentioned output:

```
db_state = defaultdict(list)
for d in data['dblist']['dbparameters']:
    db_details = u['db_code']
    db_nr = u['id']
    status = u['state']
    db_state[db_nr].append(db_nr)
    db_state[db_nr].append(status)
```

I would like to extract the list when key (**db_details**) is equal to variable **db_id** *(from different part of script, not visible here)*?

Then, when I get **my_list** I can achive proper output using script like this:

```
my_list = db_state.get(db_id)
if my_list is not None:
    print(f"This is list of db_nr and states for {db_id}:")
    for db_nr, status in my_list:
        print(f"{db_nr} is {status}")
else:
    print(f"No data for {db_id}!!")
```

To sum up how should I extract only list part (I called **my_list** for now) from **db_state** dictionary? I am not sure if indexing would be a good idea here. Maybe there is some other, simplier way for that?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to have your default dict as a list of tuples. you could create the dictionary as `db_state[db_nr].append((db_nr, status))`

Comment: But then, what about `db_details`? This is crutial parameter as whithout this and checking if it is equal to `db_id`, I can't find the right data for specific database.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict = {"Letters": list}
print(dict)
```

Just have list defined and add the name as the value

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need list slicing with step argument and `zip`.

**Ex:**

```
my_list = db_state.get(db_id)
if my_list is not None:
    print(f"This is list of db_nr and states for {db_id}:")
    for db_nr, status in zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2]):
        print(f"{db_nr} is {status}")
else:
    print(f"No data for {db_id}!!")
```

**Output:**

```
firstdb is online
seconddb is enabled
thirtdb is terminated
```